# Events sorting with priority/sticky

Tags: mysql

I have the following `ORDER BY` statement, which successfully sorts the records by

1. Future events `ASC`
2. Past events `DESC`

`ORDER BY`

```
pm.meta_value < CURDATE(),
(case when pm.meta_value > CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) ASC,
(case when pm.meta_value < CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) DESC
```

Now however, the request has been made that client also needs to be able to prioritise certain **future** events. For this I have added the priorities `0` (no priority), `1`, `2`, `3` (highest priority).
I haven't been able to apply this priority system to upcoming events only.

Below statement does work for sorting **all** events by priority, but not just the **future** events:

```
#1 pm2.meta_value DESC, # pm2.meta_value = priority
#2 pm.meta_value < CURDATE(), # pm.meta_value = date
#3 (case when pm.meta_value > CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) ASC,
#4 (case when pm.meta_value < CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) DESC
```

When I flip line `#1` and `#2` around, it does successfully order inside future and past, but I just need the future events to be sorted like this.

So basically I need the priority to be added, only `when pm.meta_value > CURDATE()`

How do I get around this?

**Full query**

```
      SELECT *
        FROM %2$s p
  INNER JOIN %3$s pm ON (p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = "events_startdate")
   LEFT JOIN %3$s pm2 ON (p.ID = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = "events_priority")
  INNER JOIN `%4$sicl_translations` ON
    (`%4$sicl_translations`.element_id = p.ID AND `language_code` = "%5$s")
       WHERE p.post_status = "publish"
         AND p.post_type = "%1$s"
    ORDER BY
             pm.meta_value < CURDATE(),
             pm2.meta_value DESC,
             (case when pm.meta_value > CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) ASC,
             (case when pm.meta_value < CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) DESC
```

Comment: Could you please paste your full SQL? You're using aliases that can mean many things.

Comment: I've added it now, but were also comments in the second clause with the meaning. `pm.meta_value = date`, `pm2.meta_value = priority`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually managed to fix my own question now, although I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

The clause now looks like this:

```
#1 pm.meta_value < CURDATE(),
#2 (case when pm.meta_value > CURDATE() then pm2.meta_value end) DESC,
#3 (case when pm.meta_value > CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) ASC,
#4 (case when pm.meta_value < CURDATE() then pm.meta_value end) DESC
```

On line `#2`, I just wrapped same `case` statement for the priority.

I'm very much open to improvements so I'll leave my answer "un-accepted" so someone else can get the credits. If you have a better idea, please let me know :-)